# Where should I save my image files for LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

In order to insert an image in LaTeX, I do as follows, but I get an error telling that the file 'me.jpg' is not found.

Where should I save my image files to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{me.jpg}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: same directory as your main document is the easiest place.

Comment: The simplest reason for LaTeX not to find a file is quite simple, the file doesn't exist. Take into account case sesitivity and or hidden file endings, strange symbols that doesn't get along ...

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX will find `me.jpg` if it's into the same directory of your main .tex file. If not, you need to say where is it.

I know two solutions, the first one is include `me.jpg` path in `includegraphics` command, just like `\includegraphics{/figures/me.jpg}`.

Another option could be declare all graphics path for your document with `\graphicspath` command in preamble:

```
\graphicspath{{figures}{../myfigures}...}
```